# populate google sheet row while minimising usage api

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

**Set-up**

Using gspread and the Shopify API, I'm inserting order data into a Google Sheet invoice template in Google Drive.

Per ordered SKU I have 4 variables;

1. product title & variant name
2. order quantity
3. unit price
4. total price

which are being inserted in the same row into column B, E, F and G respectively.

---

**Code**

```
# insert ordered line items
for j in range(0,len(order.line_items)):

    # insert product title and title variant
    wsheet.update_acell('B' + str(23+j),
        order.line_items[j].title + s + order.line_items[j].variant_title
            )       

    # insert quantity
    wsheet.update_acell('E' + str(23+j), order.line_items[j].quantity)       

    # price per unit
    wsheet.update_acell('F' + str(23+j),
        currency_symbol + order.line_items[j].price.replace('.',','))        

    # total price per line item
    wsheet.update_acell('G' + str(23+j),
        currency_symbol + str(
            round(float(
                order.line_items[j].price)*order.line_items[j].quantity,2
                    )).replace('.',','))
```

where `wsheet` is a priorly defined google sheet, `currency_symbol` is also priorly defined and self-explanatory and `order` is the Shopify API item.

Row 23 is the invoice template's first row that can be populated with order items. 
The code loops over the ordered SKUs and inserts the 4 variables per SKU per row.

---

**Issue**

As you can see the code updates per cell, which isn't very efficient for the Google API.

I know how to update a row at once, e.g. `wsheet.insert_row(payload, index=(23))` where `payload` is a priorly defined list containg the 4 variables.

However, this inserts the 4 variables starting from column A; I need it to insert the variables starting from column B.

Moreover, for aesthetic purposes, column B, C and D are merged per row from row 23 onwards. Something `wsheet.insert_row` doesn't take into account.

---

**Question**

How can I insert the row in one go, taking into account the starting column and merged cells?

Comment: Are you looking to do this with gspread?

Comment: Check [Worksheet.update()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.update) and [Worksheet.batch_update()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.batch_update) each uses only one API call.

Comment: did you consider writing everything to a file and using values_update to insert everything at once?